# Striped table DOM with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a table that colors odd rows yellow and even rows blue. Presently, I'm using the filter method, but that doesn't work. JavaScript returns `tableRows[i].filter` is not a function. I know this is really easy in CSS but I still want to try in JavaScript.

Any thoughts?

```js
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
  tableRows[i].filter(isOdd).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  tableRows[i].filter(isEven).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function isOdd(value) {
  if (value % 2 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (value % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isEven(value) {
  if (value % 2 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS to style the table?

Comment: I'm learning JavaScript dom stuff

Comment: `table tr:even {background: blue}` etc.

Comment: Creating a snippet give a JS error. Please fix that - a filter runs on an array, you run it on a row

Comment: What is this `filter` method you're trying to use?

Comment: @mplungjan Er, that error is what the question is about.

Comment: Error is "tableRows[i].filter is not a function"

Comment: @Brixta, JS does not work on wishful thinking

Comment: A nodelist is not an array, it has no `filter`

Comment: @melpomene [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @freginold You're not Brixsta.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hg9ce6sf/

Comment: @adeneo post as answer?

Comment: @freginold  So the fitler method doesn't work here because tableRows is a nodelist, which is a JavaScript Object instead of an array.

Comment: No need for filter nor isEven: `for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
      tableRows[i].style.backgroundColor = isOdd(i)? "yellow":"blue";
    }`

Comment: @Brixsta No, it doesn't work here because `tableRows[i]` is a (single) DOM node, not an array.

Comment: @melpomene Is a DOM node an object with properties or some other value type?

Comment: @Brixsta I'm pretty sure it's an object (but so are arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do odd/even stuff in JavaScript is to use the *[modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/modulus-operator-decrementjavascript)* operator (`%`).

See this example:

```js
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
  tableRows[i].style.backgroundColor = (i % 2)?"blue":"yellow";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic here, (i % 2)?"blue":"yellow";

Comment: It is a ternary operator and a modulus - if i divided by 2 is not 0 then blue else yellow

Comment: @Brixsta so basically, if `i` is divisible by 2 with no remainder, it will be yellow (because `i % 2` would equal `0`, which is `false` in JavaScript); else it will be blue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS instead, applying the `:nth-child(odd)` and `(even)` selectors:

```css
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Edit:**
If you really want to use JavaScript, though, you can just call the [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function on your `NodeList` of rows instead of using `filter`. A `for`-loop can also be substituted for `forEach`, if you prefer, but I tend to use the more [declarative approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).

```js
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')

[].forEach.call(tableRows, function (row, i) {
  row.style.backgroundColor = isEven(i) ? 'blue' : 'yellow'
})

function isEven (x) {
  return x % 2 === 0
}

function isOdd(x) {
  return x % 2 !== 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: or just keep his simpler for loop

Comment: I tend to prefer the declarative approach. I added a note to the answer explaining that the `for`-loop option is equally valid, though.